How to pytest parametrize over a list of instance method getters?
I have a class that has several getter methods:
class ExampleClass:
  def __init__(self):
    # impl omitted

  def getter1(self):
    # impl omitted
  
  def getter2(self):
    # impl omitted

I want to write a single unit test that parametrizes over all the getters (in this particular case they should return the same thing)
So I want to do something like this
@pytest.mark.parametrize('getter_method', ['getter1', 'getter2'])
def test_exampleclass_getters(getter_method):
    inst = ExampleClass()
    with raises(ValueError):
        getattr(bid, getter_method)(OVN_END_DT)

But I read that getattr is bad practice and should generally be avoided, though I feel like it's OK in this case. If not, are there other approaches to accomplishing what I need?

getattr is not bad practice.  In this case it could be done without, parameterizing on methods directly [ExampleClass.getter1, ExampleClass.getter2] and then passing the instance as "self" explicitly. But I don't think that's necessarily any better than dynamically fetching methods with getattr.

@wim I see, thanks. I didn't know you can do this " then passing the instance as "self" explicitly" but that makes sense
